# Get all objects of a specific developer

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

Is there any quick and easy way to get all created / programmed objects of a specific developer?

I often search something that i programmed a while ago and i want to save the time.

Greetz, Orangeman

Comment: Is version control switched on?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Version control is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have version control active, you can query the **UtilElements** table. For example:

http://www.jaestevan.com/ax-tip-exportar-lista-de-proyectos-en-microsoft-dynamics-ax

Comment: can you retrieve history using UtilElements? I thought it was just the most recent modified by & created by.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think this will help me! ;)

Comment: @AnthonyBlake no, you can't. But if you don't have version control active, this is the best approach to get the user that created the object on a layer.